# MVC data model Drop down list validation says id is required, how do I change to say name is required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

View:

```
<td>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeId) :
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("TypeId", String.Empty)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeId)
</td>
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.Types, "TypeId", "Name", purchaseauthoriserlist.TypeId);
```

Validation Message on the dropdown says:

```
"The TypeId field is required."
```

I want it to say:

```
"The Name field is required."
```

I have tried the below:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TypeMetaData))]
public partial class Type
{

}

public class TypeMetaData
{
[Display(Name = "Type")]
public int TypeId { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required.")]
```

to the `TypeId` declaration in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

`[DisplayName("Name")]`

to the declaration of TypeID in your view model or change your label to:

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeID, "Name")`

Comment: [Display(Name = "Name") ] does not work for some reason. I have tried that. Could it be the reason that I am using viewbag?